# "net ads join" fails in puppet exec but runs OK directly from command line

Tags: linux, centos, samba, puppet, kerberos

I have the following `exec` that joins a Linux (CentOS 6) host to an Active Directory domain.  When run as root from the bash terminal, it runs successfully and the host is joined to the AD domain properly.

However, when run in puppet, the `net ads join` command fails with:

> Failed to join domain: Failed to set password for machine account
>   (NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)

Here is the exec

```
exec { 'adjoin':
    command  => "kinit adjoin@AD.EXAMPLE.COM -k -t /etc/krb5.keytab && net ads join createcomputer='Machines/Servers/Linux Servers' osName='${operatingsystem}' osVer=${operatingsystemrelease} -k",
    unless   => "net ads testjoin -k | grep -q 'Join is OK'",
    provider => shell,
    user     => root,
    path     => '/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
    require  => [
        File['/etc/krb5.conf'],
        File['/etc/krb5.keytab'],
    ],
    logoutput => true,
}
```

I've tried with and without the `provider` and `user` parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out I had to explicitly set a few environment variables using the `environment` parameter in exec, specifically `LOGNAME`:

```
exec { 'adjoin':
    command  => "kinit adjoin@AD.EXAMPLE.COM -k -t /etc/krb5.keytab && net ads join createcomputer='Machines/Servers/Linux Servers' osName='${operatingsystem}' osVer=${operatingsystemrelease} -k",
    unless   => "net ads testjoin -k | grep -q 'Join is OK'",
    provider => shell,
    user     => root,
    path     => '/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
    require  => [
        File['/etc/krb5.conf'],
        File['/etc/krb5.keytab'],
    ],
    logoutput => true,
    environment => [
        'USER=root',
        'LOGNAME=root',
        'HOME=/root',
    ],
}
```

Two reasons for this:

1. [net ads -k join fails without LOGNAME env variable](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=957087)
2. [LOGNAME, USER, and HOME are specifically unset by puppet](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/5224) during
   an exec's run.  It was a design choice that is detailed in the
   ticket I linked to.

I also set USER and HOME for sanity's sake, though I'm not sure they are required by `net ads`.